# Gradle test run fails after class rename

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We have Gradle set up to build and test our Android app. Now we ran into the problem, that **Gradle test runs fail** reproducibly after a class was renamed somewhere in the project:

```
Execution failed for task ':PROJ:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
> Unable to read class file: '/path/to/class/with/the/name/before/renaming.class'
```

This error is reproducible both..

- **locally** (run gradle tests from Android Studio, or on command line using `./gradlew test`), and
- **remotely**, when the tests run on our CI (a Teamcity server).

What *solves* the issue, is manually triggering a rebuild locally (e.g. in Android Studio *Build > Rebuild Project*) or re-running the Teamcity task with the flag `clean all files in the checkout directory before the build` set.

**Is there any way we can get our tests to not fail after a class has been renamed?**

While the above solution is simple enough it is kinda annoying that a simple rename which makes it to our repo will blow up the CI builds... We really want those to stay green. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218273) in Gradle 2.14 and 2.14.1 and there will be a workaround for it in upcoming Android Gradle plugin release.

As a workaround you can do a clean build for your project. For a CI build, a clean build is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Swabra build feature of TC that cleans out the working directory either before or after each build, so that all generated files are blown away and the build always starts with a clean working copy. For reproducible builds this is a must-be-used feature in my opinion.

Alternatively you can of course also add the `clean` Gradle task to your TC configuration so that Gradle cleans away previous build artefacts. But if using TC I'd prefer Swabra as it restores VCS state reliably.